# PHP echo img src

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I got something like this: `print '<img src="'.$rlink.'">';`
it shows me right link, but image doesn't appear. When I go to browser console, I get this error: http://somesite.com/somesite.com/thisimage.jpg
I tried `<img src="<? php echo $rlink; ?>"/>`
It is not working. I was looking around forums but didn't found a solution. Thank you for any help!

Comment: what is the value of `$rlink` variable

Comment: It means the URL to the image is wrong. Without knowing a) what URL that is exactly and b) what it *should* be, we obviously can't help you a whole lot here.

Comment: Is `$rlink` an absolute or relative url?

Comment: $rlink is somesite.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your variable `$rlink` contains `somesite.com/thisimage.jpg`. Since it doesn't have a protocol at the beginning, the browser thinks it's a relative path, thus trying to go to `somesite.com` folder, which doesn't exist. You can either put `http://` at the beginning of the `src`, or remove domain so it's treated like the relative path it is as of now

Comment: OMG IT WORKED thanks man!!!

Comment: No problem, glad it worked out for you

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="<? php echo $rlink; ?>"/>
```

needs to be:

```
<img src="<?php echo $rlink ?>">
```

it might not solve the problem because i dont kno what the value of the variable is. It might be wrong.